# Isn't any set in R the union of closed sets?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

So for example, the set (0, 1) contains the closed subsets {1/2}, {3/4}, {pi - 3}, etc. These are simply sets of a single number.

Can it not be expressed as the union of all the closed sets of the form {x}, where 0 < x < 1? Consequently, every set in R can be expressed as the union of either a finite or infinite number of closed sets.

But (0, 1) is an uncountable set, so it would be a union of an uncountable number of closed sets. So ultimately, my question boils down to, is the union of an uncountable number of sets even possible, or can unions only have a finite or countably infinite number of sets?

Comment: Unions (and intersections) can be over an arbitrary index set. In particular, uncountable unions (and intersections) are fine. And yes, you can write $$(0,1)=\bigcup_{x\in(0,1)} \{x\}.$$

Comment: @Dave That should be an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested, here is my comment in answer form.

Unions (and intersections) can be over an arbitrary index set. In particular, uncountable unions (and intersections) are fine. And yes, you can write $$(0,1)=\bigcup_{x\in(0,1)} \{x\}.$$

Comment: +1... For any set $X$ we have $X=\cup_{x\in X}\{x\}=\bigcup \{\{x\}:x\in X\}.$